# HTML5 error W3C Validator

Tags: html, forms

I get the following error in the W3C Validator:

> The for attribute of the label element must refer to a form control

I have the following code:

```
<label class="description" for="rating-item-3-1">Test</label>
<input id="rating-item-3-1" type="hidden" value="0" name="rating-item-3-1">
```

I was researching and this error is due to *type="hidden"*. Is there any way to fix this error?

Thanks.

Comment: You are adding a label for a hidden field? What kind of behavior are you expecting?

Answer (score 1):

According to [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H44.html):

> The label element is **not used** for the following because labels for
>   these elements are provided via the *value* attribute (for Submit and
>   Reset buttons), the *alt* attribute (for image buttons), or element
>   content itself (button)
>
> - Submit and Reset buttons ( *<input type="submit">* or *<input type="reset">*)
> - Image buttons ( *<input type="image">*)
> - Hidden input fields ( *<input type="hidden">*)
> - Script buttons (*<button>* elements or *<input type="button">*)

So, I think you got your answer.